# Yii2: Reusing Form Fields through Widget

Tags: ajax, yii2, widget, jquery-select2

I have a field that is a Select2 widget field and it's usually used in many forms, but copy pasting the same code after a while gets really annoying. Therefore I decided perhaps its best to create a widget just for this field.

The field is as follows

```
      <?= $form->field($model, 'contact_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
        'initValueText' => empty($model->contact_id) ? '' : $model->contact->contact_id . ' ' . $model->contact->fullname,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'input-sm',
            'id' => 'contact_id',
            'placeholder' => '-- Search --',
            'disabled' => $disabled,
            'onchange' => new JsExpression("get_contact_info($(this).val())"),
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'language' => [
                'errorLoading' => new JsExpression("function () { return 'Waiting for results...'; }"),
            ],
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => $fetch_url,
                'dataType' => 'json',
                'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }'),
                'results' => new JsExpression('function(data,page) { return {results:data.results.text}; }'),
            ],
            'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
            'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(contact) { return contact.text; }'),
            'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (contact) { return contact.text; }'),
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

This field utilizes Ajax Fetching, and must allow to be used in create and update forms.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction.

Comment: That's right, create a widget and configure it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solution:
a) create widget - more work, but flexible using by adding additional settings
b) create separate view and render it - faster, but no so flexible